# Hello. Can anybody tell me what's going on with this code. Can anyone explain what's is happening here

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python so I don't know much about it.

So here's the code.

```
    import string

    def ispangram(string1,alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase):

         alphaset = set(alphabet)

         alpha = set(string1.lower())

         return alphaset <= alpha

    ispangram("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

output:
     True

Comment: I've tried to answer it, but for the purposes of asking a better question you should really explain *what* you do and don't understand in the code, and where you've tried to look it up. I've guessed that it's the use of `<=` on set()'s which is uncommon (which, incidentally, I didn't know but looked up in the docs...), but for all we know, as a beginner, you could be confused by function parameter default values, by constructors, by booleans, by functions full stop, by object method syntax, or anything really.

Answer (score 2):

A pangram is a sentence which has every letter of the alphabet in it.

This code asks "*are (all the letters in the alphabet) in (the input)?*".

- *All the letters in the alphabet* comes from the builtin module `string.ascii_lowercase`.
- To make the comparison work for things like `The` and `the`, the input is converted to lowercase using `lower()`.
- The comparison is done using sets - one of Python's collection types. When the operator `<=` is used on sets, it checks if every element of the left hand set is in the right hand set ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset ).

So it literally says "*is (the set of (all the letters in the alphabet in lowercase)) a subset of (the set of (characters in the input - after converting those to lowercase))?*".